# Issue calling ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService) from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, telephonymanager

I'm trying to call `((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE).getSimOperatorName().toUpperCase();` to get the SIM carrier name from a fragment but I'm getting "cannot resolve method 'getSystemService(java.lang.String)' ", the same is working fine from an activity.

I'm trying to pass a Context to the fragment but it require an empty constructor. Any idea?

Comment: Oh sorry, I've just found the answer from there. StackExchange Androide app doesn't showing suggestion while typing question's title. Should be: `((TelephonyManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getSimOperatorName().toUpperCase();`

Comment: telephonyManager  =  ( TelephonyManager )getActivity.getSystemService( Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE );